# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: - laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Am trying to open my edit form from the list of displayed data but I got the above error. Here is my Controller to display the page:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $assets = Asset::all();
    $tenants = Tenant::all();
    $tenantProperty = TenantProperty::find($id);
    return view('agent/edit_tenantProperty', compact('tenantProperty', 'assets', 'tenants'));
}
```

my view

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('agent/edit_tenantProperty/'. $tenantProperty->id) }}" data-toggle="validator">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
```

while the route is this

```
Route::get('edit_tenantProperty/{id}', [ 'as' => 'agent/edit_tenantProperty', 'uses' => 'TenantPropertyController@edit']);
```

Please help me, how can I solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: `tenantProperty` is null when you pass it to your view. You should verify the contents of of it before compacting it and sending it to be rendered

Comment: how do I verify the content?

Comment: add if condition before move to view 
if($tenantProperty){ // Load View} else { echo 'No record';}

Comment: Just checked, its not empty truly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be check `$tenantProperty` exist in controller and if not exist send not found response.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $assets = Asset::all();
    $tenants = Tenant::all();
    $tenantProperty = TenantProperty::find($id);

    if (empty($tenantProperty)) { 
        // returny tenantProperty not fount response
    }

    return view('agent/edit_tenantProperty', compact('tenantProperty', 'assets', 'tenants'));
}
```

or check `$tenantProperty` exists in view

```
@if ($tenantProperty)
   <form method="post" action="{{ url('agent/edit_tenantProperty/'. $tenantProperty->id) }}" data-toggle="validator">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
@endif
```

Comment: Truly its not there, how do I fix this. Cos table has an id with data to display

Comment: Sorry i dont understand what do you meen??

Comment: TenantProperty::find($id); return instance of **TenantProperty** or null. You can check using **is_null($tenantProperty)**, or **empty($tenantProperty)**  if this methods return true that means there is no record in your table where 'id' equel $id value

Comment: What could be responsible for $tenantProperty to be empty

Comment: for example you $id =1 but in the tenantProperty table does not have record where id =1. In that case $tenantProperty will be null

Comment: Thanks for the response

Comment: That case make it accepted for other people also can use this answer